# Assigning received image data from JSON to collection view in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I'm able to receive image data from a JSON response and I am even able to convert it to image using:

```
let json33 = JSON(data: response.data!)

let allImageStrings = json33["response"]["docs"].flatMap { $0.1["imageData"].first?.1}                    
                for Bro in allImageStrings{

                    let url = NSURL(string: Bro.string!)
                    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)!
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    self.anArray.append(image!)


                }

self.items = self.anArray
```

I've created `typealias ItemInfo = UIImage` and  `private var items: [ItemInfo] = []
    private var anArray: [ItemInfo] = []`.

And I'm assigning the `anArray` to another array which I can use outside the for-loop `items` which is declared as `private var items: [ItemInfo] = []`. And in the function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
guard let cell = cell as? CollectViewCell else { return }

    let index = indexPath.row % 4
    let info = items[index]
    //cell.backgroundImageView?.image = self.items //error here
    //cell.customTitle.text = info.title
    cell.cellIsOpen(cellsIsOpen[indexPath.row], animated: false)
}
```

I've added `@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!` to my cell too.

How do I assign the obtained base64 images and I'm even converting them to `UIImage`, to the collection view cells? Thanks.

Comment: Add a `UIImageView` as a subview to `CollectViewCell`'s `contentView`. Then assign the image to that image view's `image` property.

Comment: I've done that too @AaronBrager. But in vain. I'm using a nib file to load the cells. The cells are not displayed at all. :(

Comment: Then why doesn't your question say that??

Comment: There you go. Help please?